# How to get last consumed offset for a consumer group?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have two consumers in a consumer group which have assigned same kafka topic partitions. I wish to get last read offset of say, consumer A from inside consumer B. Any Idea, how to implement this?

Comment: Are you trying to have more than one consumer consuming in parallel from a single partition?

Comment: @LucianoAfranllie Similar but i can make consumers read in parallel but i wish to only keep track of last read offset of another consumer in kafka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single partition will never be assigned to two consumer instances in the same group.

You can use the below script to know the last consumed offset

```
sh kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --new-consumer --group groupname --describe
```

Comment: Why will it be not assigned, keep in mind i am saying assigned and not subscribed.

Comment: If you manually assign a partition, then it behaves as a Simple consumer (low -level consumer). Mind your language.

Comment: Not to sound arrogant, but now how do you think i should go on to implement the question?

Comment: Will you run the consumers within a single / multiple JVM? Where are you going to store read offset in Kafka / other data store?

Comment: Consumers will run in multiple JVM and the offset is being stored in kafka only.

Comment: I am getting `Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: new-consumer is not a recognized option`

Answer (score 3):

Kafka store offsets by (consumer-group-id, topic, partition) so the first thing to note is that from Kafka point of view there is no such thing like "last read offset of consumer A". All information that you can get with the Kafka consumer API is for a given (group, topic, partition). You have two methods in consumer API that may be useful.

[commited()](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#committed(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition)): Get the last committed offset for the given partition (whether the commit happened by this process or another).

[position()](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#position(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition)): Get the offset of the next record that will be fetched (if a record with that offset exists).

If that is not what you need, then you will have to implement something yourself. Assuming you already know how to get the last offset read from consumer A, then consumer A should store that value in some location that is available to consumer B. This location could be

- Kafka itself. For example consumer A can publish last read offset to
  a well know topic like ConsumerA-p0 and Consumer B can subscribe to
  this topic.
- Zookeeper. Again, agreeing in a well known path.
- An external database.
- More rudimentary options if both consumers share the same OS: IPC, a file in the file system, a variable in memory protected with a lock, etc.

Comment: I agree with you and theoretically it looks plausible but i wish to know whether there is certain functionality being provided by kafka itself to serve the purpose

Comment: Added more detail to my answer. I think those are all the options that you have.

Comment: +1 as above is helpful when you want to find the offset details from client code(java , C# etc)  to write some failover or specific logic Programmatically .

Answer (score 2):

use below command at **kafka->bin** change your group id with **groupId**:

`sh kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --group groupId --describe`

you will get output like:

```
TOPIC  PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
topic1 0          0               35              35              -               -               -
topic2 0          1600            1600            0               -               -               -
```